# How can I have sass variables accessed within a Webpack import?

Tags: reactjs, sass, webpack

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how I can access Sass variables within a React component's sass file import. Here's my current directory structure, where I'm using Webpack to bundle everything:

```
components/
  Sample/
    Sample.jsx
    Sample.scss
sass/
  main.scss
  variables.scss
```

Inside of `Sample.jsx`, I am importing `Sample.sccs`, however, the variables from variables.scss are not coming through, as I assume since they are separate modules, they don't share the same context?

I understand that I could fix this by simple not requiring the styles within the components's `.jsx` file but rather just import them all individually within `main.scss`, so they share the same context, but it would be nice to keep everything encapsulated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `variables.scss` in the `components/Sample/Sample.scss` file.

Add the following at the top of `components/Sample/Sample.scss` file:

```
@import "../../../sass/variables.scss";
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking but decided to just include all component `.scss` inside of `main.scss` as it seems a bit cleaner, IMHO.